# Drupal 7: Modifying menu title

Tags: php, drupal, menu

I would like to know how I can modify the menu title within the template.php of the theme I am using.

So far, I have been able to modify both the UL and LI elements by using hooks: `THEME-NAME_menu_tree__MENU-NAME` and `THEME-NAME_menu_link__MENU-NAME` respectively. However, I cannot access the menu title form either of those (or at least that's what I think). I have tried to use the `THEME-NAME_menu__MENU-NAME` hook, but it seems that the function is simply being ignored.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is your menu added using a block within your region or do you render it directly in your `page.tpl.php`?

Comment: it is added using a block, created a new menu and added it to sidebar second region. basically what i'm trying to do is add a span element between the h2 tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your menu is generated within a block. You should be able to change the subject / title by preprocessing the block. For example, change all subjects of blocks and wrap a `<span>` around it.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $block = $variables['block'];
  $block->subject = sprintf('<span>%s</span>', $block->subject);
}
```

Comment: cannot vote up because i don't have 15 rep, but yes, this is exactly what i needed. i added an if to make sure that this applies only to a specific block, other than that this is a perfect solution. thank you!